# Is using specialization for tables which only differ by many-to-many relationships right?

Tags: database, database-design

Imagine I have the specialization (teacher, student) and generalization (person) tables with ***always same*** properties (in this scenario):

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id            INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name    VARCHAR(50)   not null,
    last_name     VARCHAR(75)   not null
);

CREATE TABLE teacher (
    person_id     INTEGER       REFERENCES person (id),
    first_name    VARCHAR(50)   not null,
    last_name     VARCHAR(75)   not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE student (
    person_id     INTEGER       REFERENCES person (id),
    first_name    VARCHAR(50)   not null,
    last_name     VARCHAR(75)   not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE assigned_exam (
    person_id     INTEGER       REFERENCES person (id),
    exam_id       INTEGER       REFERENCES exam (id),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id, exam_id)
);

CREATE TABLE student_exam (
    id            INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
    exam_name     VARCHAR(50)   not null
);
```

Specialization is normally described with the specialized table having different properties. But in this scenario there is only different many-to-many relationships. The assigned_exam is ***only*** applicable if the type is a student.

Now I feel that I have two options:
1. I put everything in the person table since the properties are all the same
2. I split the tables like I have done currently

My concern with option 1 is, I am not able to model the constraints properly.
My concern with option 2 is, I will end up with tables which look exactly the same. It feels wrong.

Comment: Attributes may be the same, but predicates are not. There is no need for `_name` in `teacher`, `student`, you get them from `person`. Can a same person be both: teacher and student?

Comment: No it can only be either a student or a teacher.

Comment: Then a type-discriminator `person_type` should be added to `person`. Search for "subtype", plenty of examples on SO.

Comment: Yes I know but the intention of this question is to find out whether inheritance/specialization is also a logical way of modelling a database when the properties are the same, but the relationships differ.